# Azure Data Studio will not connect to MSSQL server on Debian 10

Tags: sql-server, debian, azure-data-studio

I have a fresh install of Debian 10 on VirtualBox.  Installed ADS from Microsoft package repository.  When I try to create an MSSQL database connection the app just sits and spins with high CPU.  ADS never connects.  On the same VM I can connect to the server using DBeaver.  I can also connect ADS to a Postgresql database without issue.

ADS works fine on a Kubuntu VM and a Centos VM.  Anyone know what could be going on with the Debian install?

The renderer log shows the connect created, but the app just sits there without finishing:

```
[2020-07-07 08:20:32.149] [renderer1] [info] Creating new connection connection:providerName:MSSQL|applicationName:azdata|authenticationType:SqlLogin|database:|server:removed|user:XXXXX|group:C777F06B-202E-4480-B475-FA416154D458
[2020-07-07 08:20:32.149] [renderer1] [info] Adding connection connection:providerName:MSSQL|applicationName:azdata|authenticationType:SqlLogin|database:|server:removed|user:XXXXX|group:C777F06B-202E-4480-B475-FA416154D458
[2020-07-07 08:20:32.149] [renderer1] [info] Successfully added connection connection:providerName:MSSQL|applicationName:azdata|authenticationType:SqlLogin|database:|server:removed|user:XXXXX|group:C777F06B-202E-4480-B475-FA416154D458
```

Thanks,
Mac

Comment: Almost same issue here, did you find solution?

Comment: Nope.  Gave up and will continue to use DBeaver.